# How change Drupal Context with a button?

Tags: 7

Context is great for delivering content to the right part of my site in the right circumstances, in the right order and to the right user.

I'd like to be able to add the ability for a user to toggle Context using a link I create - a button - to cause certain blocks to appear, disappear or be be re-arranged - via Context.

I have researched and experimented for hours and can't find a solution.

In what ways I can I change Context with the press of a button?

Comment: For future questions, don't forget to add `7` or `8` as a tag, so people know what Drupal version you are working with, thx. I answered this assuming you're using Drupal 7

Comment: There is no need to use a tag for the Drupal version. It is enough the version is reported in the question; the tag will be added if the question is pertinent for a Drupal version. For sure, a single tag like _context_ is not much helpful; at that point, it is better to use the version tag, instead of that one.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Context Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_flag)

> This module provides integration between the Context and [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag)
> (3.0+ only for the moment, if there is interest in it support for 2.0
> may be added later) modules.
>
> When enabled it creates new Context conditions which can be triggered
> based on the value of one or more Flags applied to nodes, currently
> active users, or user profile pages.
>
> [image]